installation libre office
Bonjour, je viens de procéder à la mise à niveau d'ubuntu et de passer à la version 24.04.
A la suite de cette opération la suite libre office a disparu. Merci de m'indiquer comment faire pour ré installer libre office.
Je précise que je n'ai aucune connaissance informatique et ne suis qu'un simple utilisateur de l'outil.
Merci d'avance pour l'aide apportée.
Yves

Your question makes little sense in english; are you sure you translated it to English for this english only site?

Désolé, ce site est uniquement en anglais. Veuillez traduire votre question

If I remember correctly, when you install a current version of Ubuntu Desktop, you will get Libre Office automatically. But if you install the minimal flavour, you may need to install it manually. I think it should work, if you try the following command line in a terminal window: sudo apt install libreoffice

Try this:
Open a Terminal:
Press Ctrl+Alt+T
And run:
 sudo apt update
 
 sudo apt dist-upgrade
 
 sudo apt install libreoffice
 

When you run a command with sudo, you will be asked to enter your password, it will not be written on the screen for security reasons, just type it and press ENTER
If you have any difficulties, leave a comment.
